# Производительность отрисовки GDI

Tags: c++, winapi, графика, производительность, gdi

Здравствуйте. Моя функция, вызывается при нажатии на кнопку и рисует круг(Как в `Android >5.0`). Тестировал я это дело на своём Аcer Iconia Tab w500(процесcор AMD c-60(1.0 Hz 2 ядра)), который, в общем слабенький. На нём всё рисуется плавно, красиво. Но вот, когда запустил на железе помощней, анимация стала рисоваться **так быстро**, что была ели заметна.Если изменить аргументы под мощный компьютер, то на таких слабых(и не очень), как у меня будет слишком медлено.Рисовал и через `for` и через `SetTimer()`.

Рисую примерно так:

`RECT r;
POINT cp;
GetCursorPos(&cp);
GetClientRect(hwnd,&r);
for(int i(0);i<r.right;i++)
{
   Ellipse(hdc,cp.x-i,cp.y-i,cp.x+i,cp.y+i);
}`

**Как сделать так, чтобы на любом железе рисовалось одинаково?**

Comment: А где в вашем коде SetTimer?

Comment: Не ясно в чём именно вопрос -- под что оптимизироваться? или как рисовать быстрее?

Comment: VladD, в WM_TIMER , всё аналогично рисуется

Comment: nzeemin , как сделать так, чтобы на любом железе рисовалось одинаково

Comment: Так. То есть нужно, чтобы именно _анимация_ смотрелась плавно? Тогда делаем отрисовку через таймер с небольшим интервалом, ловим WM_TIMER и в нём перерисовываем -- в чём тут проблема?

Comment: @nzeemin , дык делал так, всё равно. Тут дело, походу в времени затраченном на рисовку одного круга

Comment: @АртурКлочко У каждого железа время отрисовки одного кадра разное, следовательно нельзя сделать так чтобы везде анимировалось одинаково быстро

Comment: @arammis, да? А как же графика которую мы наблюдаем? Она везде рисуется с одинаковой скоростью. Вообще я решил выучить ассемблер и на нём написать свои ф-ии рисования.

Comment: @АртурКлочко какую графику вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: @arammis, сейчас я говорю конкретно про функции рисования `gdi`.

Comment: @arammis, ну вообще я вроде разобрался со своей проблемой. Всё упиралось, по-видимому в то, что `for` находился в `WM_PAINT`. Но тогда вопрос: как, если не через цикл можно организовать переборку неопределённого количества элементов(рисуемых объектов в моём случае)?

Comment: @АртурКлочко изображения в gdi рисуются с одинаковой скоростью дот тех пор пока не применяется анимация так как она не предназначен для быстрого рендеринга, если нужно быстро то используйте DirectX или openGL API. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface

Comment: @arammis, ну вот а DirectX написан же на языке ассемблера, вроде